# Error:Execution failed for task java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Please share full error log/stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Since December 3rd, 2014, build tools 1.0.0-rc1 was released. Now, all you need to do is modify your build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

If you are running unit tests, you will want to include this in your Application class:

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```